# XNA Stop movement when arrived

Tags: xna

I'm trying to stop movement when sprite arrive target position. But i couldn't handle it. Sprite  still move and pass target position.

Here's the code that runs every update to move it.

```
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (!IsNasted)
        {
            //Find the delta time
            float delta = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * 300;
            //Find the direction
            Vector2 direction = ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(targetPos) - 
                 ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(body.Position);
            if (direction.Length() < delta)
            {
                body.Position = targetPos;
                if (minx == movements.Count - 1) minx = 0;
                else minx++;
                targetPos = ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(movements[minx]);
            }
            else
            {
                direction.Normalize();
                //Move towards it
                currentPos = direction * delta;
                body.Position += ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(currentPos);
            } 
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

Comment: what is `movements[minx]` ?

Comment: movements is an array of vector2d which randomly generated positions.

Comment: i edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
Vector2 targetPos = new Vector2(600,100);//target location
float speed = 0.5f;

public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    //if the distance between the current position and the target position 
    //is less than 10, then move it straight to the target position
    if(Vector2.Distance(targetPos, ConvertUnits.ToDisplaUnits(body.Position) < 10)
        body.Position = ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(targetPos);
    else
    {
        //calculate velocity and move the body towards the target position
        Vector2 velocity = (targetPos - ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(body.Position)).Normalize() 
            * speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        //you can use: body.Position += ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(velocity);
        //or better use the LinearVelocity property, so that the collisions 
        //will be detected faster
        body.LinearVelocity = ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(velocity);
    }
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

You need to set a number like `10` I have set, so that the moving object won't stutter and move back and forth while trying to reach the target position. So for example if the distance between the current position and the target position is less than `10` you will just directly move it to the target position.

You need a big enough number so that it doesn't stutter, but a small enough number so that it doesn't look like your object just magically teleported to the target position. That number should basically be `(1/60)*1000*speed` (where 60 is your fps), or if that doesn't work (object stutters and never stops moving) then try `(1/60)*1000*speed + 0.5f`. It is basically `velocity.Length * speed` **but not quite**, because in the example above we calculate velocity according to the current fps (current time elapsed), but we need the "max" fps (`16.66666 * speed`). So `velocity.Length * speed` **would not work**, because if the device runs in lower fps, then there will be bugs.